# Convert an array of strings into Perl source code defining a list

Tags: perl

I am parsing some website(s) to get some information list that I store into an array of strings. I need to generate `.pm` code where this list will be defined as a Perl variable. As such strings in the array may contain any ASCII character, I need to ensure that there would be no conflict with Perl syntax. What is the best and safest way to convert such array into Perl source code?

Comment: And why does it need to be Perl source code, and not just a data file in a format like JSON or YAML you can slurp in safely in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Storable](http://p3rl.org/Storable) or [Data::Dumper](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aDumper) with `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use: `FreezeThaw`

It can `freeze` and `thaw` any element you want (or at least anything that doesn't have pointers to active objects).

If needed it also allow you to modify the `freezer` and `thawer` so that you can store data the regular function doesn't support.